# How to consume WCF service in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, wcf, c#-4.0

```
<div class="row" id="ifsc">
  <div class="col-xs-3">

    Correct Bank IFSC
  </div>
  <div class=" col-xs-3">
    <input id="correct_ifsc" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

when I enter ifsc in text than do validation of ifsc using wcf service in c#.

IFSC CODE is in json

I want to do validation of ifsc via API.

api url: `http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/{IFSCCODE}`

and refer ref: https://github.com/mangrep/ifsc-rest-api .

I want to GET THE RESPONSE FROM WCF SERVICE AND THAN will GET RESPONSE ,IF IT IS VALID THAN CALL SUCCESS RESPONSE OR INVALID THAN CALL FAILURE RESPONSE.

Comment: what you have tried so far?? btw you can use the ajax call from javascript directlly

Comment: Your question is the incoherent rambling of a drunk or madman. Please edit the question to include what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, and the exact problem you are having, along with any *relevant* code samples and/or error messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[WebMethod]

```
public static string getifsccode(string id)
{
    string url = @"http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/" + id;
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ResponseData
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
    public ResponseData CheckIFSCCodeValid(string IFSCcode)
    {

        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        string jsonString = client1.DownloadString("http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/"+ IFSCcode);
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(jsonString);
        return responseData;
    }
```

Call method like this

```
 ResponseData responseData = CheckIFSCCodeValid("SBIN0011050");
        if (responseData.status == "success")
        {
            //IFSC code is valid
        }
        else
        {
            ////IFSC code is invalid
        }
```

Comment: While your efforts are appreciated and worthy of admiration, how in the world did you understand from the question what the OP was asking?